# Consulta SQLite SELECT-FROM-WHERE. No such column

Tags: sqlite

Tengo una base de datos SQlite con una columna de nombre **Name1**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer una consulta a la base de datos SELECT-FROM-WHERE, me devuelve error.

```
SELECT id, Name1, Grup, ColSheet FROM MINE180 WHERE Name1=oro;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo qué está pasando, oro es un campo, no el nombre de la columna que es Name1, y no veo nada mal en mi sentencia SQL. Si ejecuto el mismo código con Id=1 sí que me devuelve el oro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mejor pon el código de la consulta para una respuesta en vez de poner imágenes que también esta bien. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe ser porque el campo Name1 esta compuesto de valores de tipo texto y no de tipo número como el caso de Id, entonces lo que deberías hacer sería poner lo que buscas con comillas simples 'ejemplo', entonces quedaría así:

```
SELECT id, Name1, Grup, ColSheet FROM MINE180 WHERE Name1='oro';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te esta pasando es que el valor oro lo mas seguro lo tengas como nvarchar por lo tanto tendras que hacerlo de esta manera

```
Select id, Name1, Grup, ColSheet from MINE180 WHERE Name1 = 'oro';
```

Se tiene que poner entre comillas por el nvarchar. El Id te funciona porque es un numerico y no hace falta ponerlo entre comillas.

Comment: Es por que es una cadena de texto, puede ser nvarchar o cualquier otro tipo de cadenas.